# Store and Return String outside of While loop Java

Tags: java

```
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
   String contentLine = br.readLine();
   while(contentLine!= null){
     System.out.println(contentLine);
     contentLine = br.readLine();

   }

   return contentLine; // returns null
 }
```

Hello All,
I am in process of learning java, and here i am trying to parse a file that prints out the json message, the challenge I am facing is, I need to return that json which is inside while loop. Currently, the method returns null

Comment: I tried add the line of code return contentLine += br.readLine(); 
I throws an error at "+" saying expression expected

Comment: In your loop change `contentLine = br.readLine();` to `contentLine += br.readLine();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat if you do that, you'll never get out of the loop, though

Comment: @Stultuske true, i just tried that and its not coming out of loop.

Comment: @Peter keep your code as is, and store the data to return in a different variable

Comment: @peter See the answer below, I have introduced a StringBuilder variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cement the comments above, use a different variable and then append to the returned value

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));

StringBuilder contentLine = new StringBuilder ();
while(true){
     String tmp = br.readLine();
     if (tmp == NULL) {
         break;
     }
     contentLine.append (tmp);
     System.out.println(contentLine.toString ());
}

return contentLine.toString ();
```

Comment: This worked, but the way its appending and completes the json is like this in console.

{  "page": {
{  "page": {    "size": 2,
{  "page": {    "size": 2,    "number": 2,
{  "page": {    "size": 2,    "number": 2,    "numberOfPages": 1,

Comment: you can always add a breakline each time you do .append(tmp);

Comment: @user16320675 - Absolutely agree, but just keeping with the original code.